# Converting datetime to date

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

I have indexes on tbl1.date and tbl2.datetime. When I do the following:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.datetime = tbl1.date
```

`tbl2.datetime` index gets used (as expected)

Obviously, I need to convert `tbl2.datetime` to a date in order for the `SELECT` statement to work in real life. However, doing so results in none of the indexes getting used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON DATE(tbl2.date) = tbl1.date
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
I've tried something like this but keep getting syntax error

> "#1064.... check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON DATE( SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT datetime FROM tbl2.datetime) as tem' at line 1"

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON DATE( SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT          
datetime FROM tbl2.datetime) as tempTable ) = quotes.GOOG.date
```

Comment: typo: DATE(tbl2.date) -> DATE(tbl2.datetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Nothing - you can't alter the data or data type and expect to be able to use the index.

While being altered for the comparison, there's no link between the value in the index and the value you want/need to use.  The only option is to store the value in a way that doesn't require the alteration if you want to see an index get used.

Comment: @ginius. Store your datetime in two fields, one date field, one time field. Then you can do you join efficiently (and still sort tbl1 by date and time if needed)

Comment: @Ben, thx but I would rather not have 2 columns in my table but you did give me an idea....I just updated my question....I tried putting tbl2.datetime in a temporary table but it won't work.

Comment: The temporary table statement works fine but when I try to do a JOIN and a temp table then it won't work and I get the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. As a workaround I tried to isolate the `DATETIME` on one hand of the JOIN condition...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.datetime
BETWEEN CONCAT( tbl1.date,  ' 00:00:00' ) AND CONCAT( tbl1.date,  ' 23:59:59' )
```

FWIW, it was a FAIL.